# To Create data in the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why data in the firebase are created this way and not in the normal way

[image]

[image]

this is my code

```
ProductRef.child(IdMesa_1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        facturas.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()`, you're converting a branch of your JSON tree into a string. When you then write that back to Firebase, it saves it as a string.

If you want to save it in the same structure as before, don't convert the data to a string. So:

```
ProductRef.child(IdMesa_1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        facturas.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```